# ejabberd MUC-SUB Event Notification till the MUC invite is accepted

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, publish-subscribe, multiuserchat

I am using Ejabberd's MucSub approach to implement a mobile group chat client. A user Creates a Room and sends MUC Invites to the users that must be the members to this group.The clients are configured to auto-accept the MUC invitations and then subscribe to the room's pubsub node for various events.

However the problem with this is that, **a user that in not online will not receive any published event till he's not subscribed to the node** and this can not happen until the user comes online once, Hence sending push notifications to such users for these events in not possible.

**What should be the approach to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Sending an invitation to a given user is send as a direct message to the user. It is also stored in offline storage, so the user will get it on reconnect.

For example:

1. UserA sends this MUC invite for `room@conference.localhost` to userB, userB being offline:

   ```
   <message to='room@conference.localhost'>
     <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
       <invite to='userB@localhost'/>
     </x>
   </message>
   ```
2. When UserB connects, he will receive the invite:

   ```
   <message from="room@conference.localhost" type="normal" to="userB@localhost">
    <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
     <invite from="userA@localhost/laptop">
      <reason/>
     </invite>
    </x>
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" jid="room@conference.localhost"/>
    <body>userA@localhost/laptop invites you to the room room@conference.localhost</body>
    <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="localhost" stamp="2016-11-09T08:10:58.063Z">Offline Storage</delay>
   </message>
   ```

When userB receives the offline message on connect, he can subscribe to MUC events.

Comment: Yes @Mickaël Rémond, Thats exactly how I have implemented it, the only issue I have is I want to generate push notifications for the messages sent to room before the user accepts the invite and subscribe. Any possibility we can achieve that in some way ?

Comment: Well, it is a custom use case, so you have to implement this yourself in some way. Most deployment will not want to push notifications for all messages in a chat room before the user accept the invitation. It feels like push spam.